# Inconsistent behavior across browsers with conditionally declared functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Google Chrome alerts "Hello!" while Mozilla Firefox alerts "Hi!" when running this code:

```
    if (true) {
      function hello() {
        alert("Hi!");
      }
      hello();
    } else {
      function hello() {
        alert("Hello!");
      }
      hello();
    }
```

However, when written as function expressions, both browsers will return "Hi!"

```
    var hello;

    if (true) {
      hello = function() {
        alert("Hi!");
      }
      hello();
    } else {
      hello = function() {
        alert("Hello!");
      }
      hello();
    }
```

I don't understand this inconsistent behavior across browsers with conditionally declared functions?

Is it a bug in JavaScript or Browser or it's wrong to declare functions directly in conditional statements?

Comment: Function definition statements shouldn't appear in conditional blocks. I'm looking for a good reference on the topic, but due to the way function definitions (and `var` declarations, similarly) are hoisted, it's inherently "fishy".

Comment: function declarations are always hoisted to the top of the function, so you cannot put them inside if/then. The last one will overwrite any earlier ones if they have the same name. You should get into the habit of always writing them at the very top (of the function/scope they are declared in) so that what you see matches what happens. function expressions, when you assign an anon. function to a variable, can be put anywhere.

Comment: [Here is a relevant bug from the Mozilla repository.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=609832)