# Do inner functions in JavaScript get hoisted? How do the scoping rules apply to them?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, declaration, hoisting

I thought that JavaScript doesn't have block scope, but function scope, and that declarations are hoisted from their block to the top of their parent functions.

However, the following code does not work as expected:

```
function one(a) {
    console.log("one called for " + a);

    if (a == 1) {
        function inner(b) {
            console.log("inner called for " + b);
        }

        inner(123);
    }

    inner(456);
}

one(1);
one(2);
one(3);
```

The first `one(1);` call proceeds normally, without any errors, however the execution stops when the second `one(2);` is called.

This behavior is intuitive: the function `inner` is defined only if `a==1`.

**But how is it consistent with the scoping/hoisting rules?**

I thought its definition would be hoisted to the top of its scope, outside of the `if` block which is supposed to have no effect!

**Edit:** here are the errors I am getting:

[image: screenshot of Firefox console showing the error]

Browser is Firefox. [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5sP/)

Comment: Worked for me - http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5sP/

Comment: @MarkWalters Take another look at the console. There are errors.

Comment: I can assure you there are no errors in the console

Comment: Well, I'm looking at your fiddle and there are :/

Comment: What browser are you in?

Comment: Latest firefox using Firebug.

Comment: Look at the question, I posted the error I'm getting *in your fiddle.* I'm using Nightly (Firefox).

Comment: i'm using chrome and I don't get the reference error for inner not being defined

Comment: @MarkWalters: makes the question that more interesting :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm not getting it in Chrome.

Comment: Here's another question i've found which may shed some light - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302057/inconsistent-behavior-across-browsers-with-conditionally-declared-functions-in-j

Comment: Here's a reference to the bug in Firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=609832

Comment: You have +1 Googlefu.

Comment: In Chrome it works fine, but this is borderline code. Try "use strict" and only consider browsers that actually have a 100% ES5-strict-compliant implementation.

Comment: @Andy Danke Schon. I was born to Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (…) {
>     function …() {            
>         …
>     }
> }
> ```

is invalid ECMAScript. Function declarations must be on the top level of function or program bodies, inside of blocks [their behaviour is implementation-dependent](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks). Firefox does execute this *function statement* conditionally, other browsers do hoist it like a normal *function declaration*. Move it outside the if-statement, or assign a function expression.

Comment: *Function declarations must be on the top level of function or program bodies* - but isn't the example you posted 'on the top level of function'?

Comment: No, it's inside the if-body block

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `inner` is hoisted to the top of the outer function. However, its value is only set if `a == 1`.

When `outer()` is called with a different value, the call to `inner(456)` fails as `inner` is still set to `undefined`.