# Javascript difference between function and constructor syntax?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I have studied Javascript for a litte while now but I can't seem how to spot the difference if a statement is a function or constructor. This is the code for a Constructor:

```
function Book (pages, author) {
this.pages = pages;
this.author = author;
}
```

And  this is a simple function:

```
var cars = function(printCar){
console.log(blabla);
};
```

However I have seen in serveral tutorials(i.e CodeCademy) that they are using the constructor syntax for making functions aswell. How is this possible?

Comment: The difference you mentioned is actually between function expression and function statement.

Comment: There's a mistake in your "simple function" example; I'm not sure if you meant to say var something = function(printCar) or if you meant function something(printCar).

Comment: Constructors start with a captial letter, unless a fool coded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntactic difference. All (user-defined) functions can be called both as a function/method or as a constructor. Whether it's a [function declaration or a expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) doesn't matter:

```
var Book = function() { … };
function Book() { … }
var example = function() { … };
function example() { … };
```

However, [naming functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) is always encouraged, and there's no reason to write `var example = function() { … }` when you can use a declaration. There are some cases though where an expression (which is typically anonymous) is required, or where [declarations are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21987820/1048572).

What they are and what they do is entirely determined by their body code. Constructors typically set properties on [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), however methods will do that as well. Constructors usually have no `return` statement, as the [`new` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572) implicitly returns the created instance.

A convention for distinguishing them is that constructor functions have a capitalized name.

Comment: Okay! Then I understand, thanks. Is it beter to use the "function syntax" or the "Constructor syntax" when creating functions? Or that doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but as he said it's about convention.  So from that perspective, it probably is slightly more maintainable to write functions using function syntax and constructors using constructor syntax.  So the next guy maintaining your code has a bit more clarity on  your intent.

Comment: @Baxtex: there is no "function" or "constructor" syntax. You probably mean the distinction in "function expressions" and "function declarations", see the link I've posted. Declarations are better if you can use them.